# Lista pegando pagina toda do android

Tags: android, android-layout

Pessoal minha `listview` está saindo fora, preciso que ela pegue apenas partes, sou péssimo em layout `android` e a expectativa esta totalmente diferente da realidade kkkk

Preciso que fique assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E esta assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Se conseguir fixa a lista um uma parte apenas da tela ja ajudaria. Depois é a dificuldade de fazer o layout do card.

O XML da `activity` está assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#F9F9F9" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout="@layout/toolbar_default" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/lytContato"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"
    android:padding="7dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgLogoRestaurante"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="29dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cart_lyt"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/nmRestaurante"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Nome da Empresa"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/apptheme_color"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imgLogoRestaurante"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <RatingBar
        android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:progressBackgroundTint="@color/background"
        android:progressTint="@color/primary_color"
        android:stepSize="0.5"
        android:layout_below="@+id/nmRestaurante"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:isIndicator="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lytComentarios"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lisComentarios"
    style="@style/listViewStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/lytEmptyComentarios"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgChapeu"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_fab_star" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:text="Não existem comentarios para esta empresa."
        android:textColor="#999999"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"/>
</LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

E aqui meu XML do item card:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp">

<TextView
    android:textColor="@color/primary_text"
    android:id="@+id/nmCliente"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/nmCliente"
    android:layout_below="@+id/observacaoAvaliacao"
    android:max="5"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:progressBackgroundTint="#A79896"
    android:progressTint="@color/accent_color"
    android:stepSize="0.5" />


<TextView
    android:textColor="@color/ampm_text_color"
    android:id="@+id/observacaoAvaliacao"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textSize="16sp" />
```

Comment: adicione na listview `android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar_actionbar"` e ve como fica

Comment: É isto resolveu, agora preciso do layout do card, não estou conseguindo de jeito nenhum

Comment: Tu quer que a lista fique abaixo do card?

Comment: Não quero os cards  da lista igual da primeira imagem.

Comment: O local dos texto, estrelas e nome, e a borda